# Sort vs Max functions

Tags: functions

Please, have a look at these two results:

```
In[1]:= Sort@{504922 Log[895447], 500894 Log[999665]}

Out[1]:= {504922 Log[895447], 500894 Log[999665]}
```

and

```
In[2]: Max@{504922 Log[895447], 500894 Log[999665]}

Out[2]: 504922 Log[895447]
```

It's nice, is it not? Something's wrong with Sort, OrderedQ, MaximalBy etc.? I'll  greatly appreciate any comments.

P.S. The numbers are from the problem 99 of [projecteuler.net](http://projecteuler.net)

Comment: see help for Sort, under possible issues.

Answer (score 7):

Try [`NumericalSort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericalSort.html):

```
NumericalSort @ {504922 Log[895447], 500894 Log[999665]}
```

> ```
> {500894 Log[999665], 504922 Log[895447]}
> ```

or use [`NumericalOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericalOrder.html) as the ordering function in the second argument of `Sort`:

```
Sort[#, NumericalOrder] &@{504922 Log[895447], 500894 Log[999665]}
```

> ```
> {500894 Log[999665], 504922 Log[895447]}
> ```

or use `SortBy[N]` instead of `Sort`:

```
SortBy[N]@{504922 Log[895447], 500894 Log[999665]}
```

> ```
> {500894 Log[999665], 504922 Log[895447]}
> ```

For `Max` you can use

```
MaximalBy[N] @ {504922 Log[895447], 500894 Log[999665]}
```

> ```
> {504922 Log[895447]}
> ```

***Is something wrong with Sort?***

[`Sort >> Possible Issues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html)

- ***Numeric expressions are sorted by structure as well as numerical value***

For example:

```
Sort[{Pi, 10 , Log[10]}]
```

> ```
> {10, π, Log[10]}
> ```

vs

```
NumericalSort[{Pi, 10 , Log[10]}]
```

> ```
>  {Log[10], π, 10}
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I do understand that 
N@{504922 Log[895447], 500894 Log[999665]}
Sort@%
give correct results. The question is why sort of integers works wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `Less` to sort by numerical

```
list = {504922 Log[895447], 500894 Log[999665]};
Sort[list, Less]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
Sort[list]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, a good idea, It means that the default ordering function in Sort gives wrong result in this case, is it?

Comment: No, it’s not wrong — the criterion in this case just isn’t the numerical value (“sorted by structure”). I agree this is weird, and pretty rarely what you’d actually want, but it generalises time

Comment: Ok. So it seems that sorting expressions like a Log[b], Sort by default first pays attention to b and then to a. See , e.g. Sort@{1/2 Log[5], 2 Log[5], 5 Log[2]} and NumericalSort@{1/2 Log[5], 2 Log[5], 5 Log[2]}